# Deleting old account or merging an account

Tags: support

I have this account which is quite old and in my new account I require the email which is being used here. Anyway the email can be freed up?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions here to merge your profiles: https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge.